# Javascript function not changing the css of an html div on call

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am trying to create a function for my game of pong for the ball to move around within a frame. When I call the function I am using a function called setStyle() to change the position of the ball every 100 milliseconds.

After I saw that it did not work I console logged the left and top positions to find that the function was getting called but the amount of pixels it was located at was the same.

```
//Javascript

function ballMove(){
  var x = 5;
  var y = 5;
  var maxHeight = getStyle('frame', 'top') + getStyle('frame', 'height');
  var maxWidth = getStyle('frame', 'left') + getStyle('frame', 'width');
  var ballLeft = getStyle('ball', 'left');
  var ballTop = getStyle('ball', 'top');
  var minLeft = getStyle('frame', 'left');
  var minTop = getStyle('frame', 'top');
  if(ballTop >= minTop){
    setStyle('ball', 'top', (ballTop + y) + "px");
  }
  else if(ballTop <= maxHeight){
    setStyle('ball', 'top', (ballTop - y) + "px");
  }
  if(ballLeft >= minLeft){
    setStyle('ball', 'left', (ballLeft + x) + "px");
  }
  else if(ballLeft <= maxWidth){
    setStyle('ball', 'left', (ballLeft - x) + "px");
  }
  console.log(ballLeft);
  console.log(ballTop);
}
function startIntervals(){
  setInterval(ballMove, 100);
  console.log("starting...");
}
```

Here is my css

```
#ball{
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

and the html

```
<body onload="startIntervals();">
    <div id="main-div">
      <div id="title">Pong</div>
      <div id="frame">
        <div id="paddlewasd">
          </div>
          <div id="paddlearrow">
            </div>
            <div id="ball">
              </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

I expected the ball to move but instead the function gets called and the left and top positions stay the same.[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP4XQ.png)

Comment: Please format the code in your question properly.

Comment: Can you include your html and css as well?

Comment: What library are you utilizing for getStyle() setStyle() ?

Comment: I created my own getStyle and setStyle functions to make life easier, I have used them before and they have always worked fine

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a problem with the code you've posted - so maybe the error is located somewhere in the bits you didn't share. Try to include a working example (including the function definition for get/setStyle).

Comment: Um, what is `getStyle` and `setStyle`?

Comment: what is getStyle and setStyle do ? what is getStyle and setStyle paramaters ? what is getStyle and setStyle return ? **what is getStyle and setStyle**

Comment: #divid{color:blue;} - if I wanted to know what the value of divid's color was I would call getStyle("idname(divid)", "property(color)"); or to change something I would call setStyle("idname(divid)", "property(color)", "value(green)");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it depends fairly significantly on the rest of the code that wasn't posted the following implementations of **getStyle** and **setStyle** along with a css defintion of **#frame** allows the ball to move diagonally 5pixels right and down every 100 milliseconds

```js
function getStyle(id, style) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element);
  var selectedStyle = computedStyle[style];

  // Check if the style value matches a 'pixel' string format, if it does extract the numeric part and parse it as an integer
  var pixelTokens = /([\d]*)px$/.exec(selectedStyle);
  if (pixelTokens) {
    return parseInt(pixelTokens[1]);
  }

  return selectedStyle;
}

function setStyle(id, style, value) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  return element.style[style] = value;
}

function ballMove() {
  var x = 5;
  var y = 5;
  var maxHeight = getStyle('frame', 'top') + getStyle('frame', 'height');
  var maxWidth = getStyle('frame', 'left') + getStyle('frame', 'width');
  var ballLeft = getStyle('ball', 'left');
  var ballTop = getStyle('ball', 'top');
  var minLeft = getStyle('frame', 'left');
  var minTop = getStyle('frame', 'top');
  if (ballTop >= minTop) {
    setStyle('ball', 'top', (ballTop + y) + "px");
  } else if (ballTop <= maxHeight) {
    setStyle('ball', 'top', (ballTop - y) + "px");
  }
  if (ballLeft >= minLeft) {
    setStyle('ball', 'left', (ballLeft + x) + "px");
  } else if (ballLeft <= maxWidth) {
    setStyle('ball', 'left', (ballLeft - x) + "px");
  }
  console.log(ballLeft);
  console.log(ballTop);
}

function startIntervals() {
  setInterval(ballMove, 100);
  console.log("starting...");
}
```

```css
#ball {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  left: 50px;
}

#frame {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body onload="startIntervals();">
  <div id="main-div">
    <div id="title">Pong</div>
    <div id="frame">
      <div id="paddlewasd">
      </div>
      <div id="paddlearrow">
      </div>
      <div id="ball">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```